# Regularity of minimizing harmonic maps with no topological obstructions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity

So during (not really) my research I stumbled upon the following question, for which I could not find results in literature in any direction. It is not stated super precisely mathematically speaking, but I hope someone can give some ideas or references.

Let $(M^m, g)$ and $(N^n,h)$ be two compact Riemannian manifolds with $\partial N = \emptyset$ but $\partial M \neq \emptyset$. My questions are in general but to fix the ideas we can think of $m=3$ and $n=2$. Assume there exists a nontrivial continuous map $g:\partial M \to N$. I will be a bit vague on what I mean here by "nontrivial", to me anything that carries some topological information. For example, we can think of $M=\overline{B_1}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, $N=\mathbb{S}^2 $ and $g$ being the identity on $\mathbb{S}^2$. Now let us minimize the Dirichlet energy prescribing the homotopy class at the boundary, that is:
$$ \inf \left\{\int_M |du|^2 dV_g \: : \: u|_{\partial M} \text{ is homotopic to } g \right\} .$$
Assume that the infimum is positive (this is my mind would follow by the "nontriviality" of $g$, but to my knowledge I don't see why necessarily the infimum couldn't be zero even if $g$ is "nontrivial", so we will assume this) and is assumed at an harmonic map $v \in H^1(M,N)$, that then is actually locally minimizing in the interior (see *Remark* at the end). By a famous result of Schoen-Uhlenbeck we know that the singular set $\text{sing}(v)$ is discrete for $m=3$ and has locally finite $(m-3)$ Hausdorff measure for $m\ge 4$. This result is clearly sharp as one can cook up easily examples with $m=3$ and the singular set being a single point.

Take $m=3$, from the examples I can think of it seems to me that the singular set is not empty (even though discrete) because there are *topological obstructions*. But this has nothing to do with harmonic maps in some sense, as the space of continuous/smooth maps $u:M\to N$ that are homotopic to $g$ on $\partial M$ could be empty. This is the case for $M=\overline{B_1}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, $N=\mathbb{S}^2 $ and $g=\text{Id}_{\mathbb{S}^2}$.

Now we come to **my questions**:

- If we *assume* that there are no topological obstructions in the problem, i.e. that there exists a smooth $\overline{u} :M \to N$ that is homotopic to $g$ on $\partial M$, is the regularity of the minimizer any better than $(m-3)$-dimensional?
- Is this true at least for $m=3$? Hence is the minimizing harmonic map smooth without topological obstructions?
- If not true, are there cheap examples where one can see why it is convenient for the minimizer to develop a singularity anyways?

*Remark*. Here maybe I am also kind of assuming many things: that my topological boundary condition is closed under the weak topology of $H^1(M,N)$ or that smooth maps are dense in $H^1(M,N)$. Let me not care about this in the exposition but if this is related to the answer please tell me.

Comment: I find even in problems with fairly complicated energy structure like this one, it's still the case that it's not topological but geometric/quantitative information that matters. In your case ($B_1 \rightarrow S^2$), imagine modifying $M$ somewhere away from the singularity of the minimizer by gluing in some tiny manifold smoothly (like a handle; set it up so the perturbed manifold admits nonvanishing vector fields normal on the boundary). Call $M_k$ a sequence of these with the glued-in portion getting smaller in volume. Let $E(M)$ the minimal harmonic map energy.

Comment: It's easy to see that $\lim E(M_k) \leq E(M)$, by using the harmonic map on $M$ extended to be approximately constant as a competitor. Let $x \in M$ be the point near which you are gluing stuff. Take the sequence of minimal harmonic maps on $M_k$: if they are smooth, they are uniformly smooth away from $x$, so their limit will be a harmonic map on $M$ which is smooth near $0$ (and minimizing, by above inequality); this is a contradiction if you know the only minimizing harmonic map on $M$ had singularity at $0$. This isn't meant to be a rigorous answer, but it's the basic heuristic argument.

Comment: @user378654 thank you for your comment, this is a very nice idea and I see your point. Nevertheless, it seems to me that this does not necessarily give a contradiction. I don't see why "if they are smooth, they are uniformly smooth away from $x$. By the $\epsilon$-regularity you know that if $E_{B_R(0)}(u_k)\le \epsilon$ then you have (say) $C^{2,\alpha}$-estimates in $B_R(0)$, but it could be that you have to choose smaller and smaller $R$ as $k$ grows to make $E_{B_R(0)}(u_k)\le \epsilon$ hold. It seems to me that a uniform (in $k$) local estimate around $0$ need not to hold.

Comment: That is true (and why the above is not a proof), but in this case I think the limiting behavior of sequences of smooth harmonic maps converging to one with a singularity is understood: you will be forced to have a finite energy drop and form (at least one) bubble. At any rate, that's what I expect here from memory, and why I wrote the above. And here, you can't have a finite energy drop.